# Merge/attach/join/put together fibonacci output lines into a single line

Tags: python

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    if n == 1:
        print(a)
    else:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        for i in range(2,n):
            c = a + b
            a = b
            b = c
            print(c)
fib(int(input()))
```

how do i make it so the output comes in a single line attached one result to another instead of receiving one sum below the other

simple append/join commands that didn't work, most likely i don't know how to properly use them in this instance
`your text`

Comment: Your function doesn't *return* anything useful. It's *printing* multiple lines to standard output. You can capture that output using things like `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, but it doesn't make a lot of sense for `fib` to be producing any output in the first place. It should *return* a list of numbers, and the caller can then produce whatever output they like from that list.

Comment: Also, `n == 1` isn't really a special case. You can iterate over `range(1, n)`, and yield `a` *before* computing `c` and changing the values of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `end` for `print` to a single space (instead of the default newline).

```py
print(a, b, end=' ')
for i in range(2,n):
    c = a + b
    a = b
    b = c
    print(c, end=' ')
print()
```

To avoid a trailing space after the last number:

```py
print(a, b, end='')
for i in range(2,n):
    c = a + b
    a = b
    b = c
    print('', c, end='')
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could unpack the results of a generator like this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

n = int(input('N: '))

print(*fibonacci(n))
```

**Example:**

```
N: 10
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```